# How do I get an absolutely positioned div to scroll when the mouse is hovering over it?

Tags: html, scroll

I have two main divs on my site .left and .right. When the pages on my site first load, .right usually has scroll bar, however, I have to click in .right to get the div to scroll. How do I get .right to scroll without having to click within it?

The css...

```
div.left, div.right 
{ 
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    bottom:0; 
    height:100%; 
    padding:0; 
}
div.left  
{ 
    right:81%; left:0; 
    width:19%; 
    overflow:auto; 
    background:#000; 
    color:#fff; 
}
div.right 
{ 
    right:0; 
    left:19%; 
    width:81%; 
    overflow-y:auto; 
    background:#fff; 
    color:#000 
}
```

Any and all help will be appreciated. Thank you for reading.
Lady Aleena

Comment: So you just want to put mouse over the div, move the mouse up and down and have the div scroll?

Comment: @Lowkase I am sorry I was not clear enough, I want the scroll wheel or arrow keys on my keyboard to work without having to click on the div.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it.  You have two divs.  You want one of them to override the arrow key and scroll wheel events for the entire page?

Comment: @Lowkase Please go to http://fantasy.xecu.net and try to scroll the page without clicking the right div.